# How to hide a certain button based on the condition that a product is out of stock?

Tags: css, woocommerce, conditional-statements

We are using a custom designed shop page, so our ad-to-cart-button is not the standard WooCommerce ad-to-cart-button. It is a regular button with the dynamic function to ad the certain product to the cart.
So it works like like the WooCommerce ad-to-cart button with the exception that it doesn't disappear when the product ist out of stock.
The goal is the make this button disappear for sold out products.

I tried to add custom css to the button:

```
.woocommerce div.product .out-of-stock {
    display: none;
}
```

But this doesn't make the button disappear, it only hides the info "out of stock" below the button.

What can I do to hide the button based on the condition that the products is out of stock?

Comment: Have you had a look to see exactly what html is there (use your browsers dev tools inspect facility). If you still can’t solve it please show us the relevant html and css.

Comment: The first question is, where do you get the information that a product is out of stock or not? This is more likely a backend question than a CSS question.